# How do I get a project with references to other projects in other solutions to build?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, teamcity

I cannot build my web projects solution that references other projects in other solutions (VS2014).

The web project references the other projects as external projects instead of the built DLLs.

The solutions each have their own github repository.
I've created a quick sample of the how the solutions relate to each other here:

- https://github.com/tonyeung/MainSolution
- https://github.com/tonyeung/LibSolution

If you open main solution, you can see that it references libsolution

```
Solution
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "LibSolution", "..\LibSolution\LibSolution\LibSolution.csproj", "{08528F48-434D-4DF5-95B9-35178E73399B}"
EndProject

Project
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\LibSolution\LibSolution\LibSolution.csproj">
```

The build log is like so (error highlighted at the bottom)

```
[14:21:41]Checking for changes
[14:21:41]Will perform clean checkout
[14:21:41]Clean checkout reasons
[14:21:41]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:21:41]Clearing temporary directory: C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[14:21:41]Checkout directory: C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\792fe8e34d5b0582
[14:21:41]Updating sources: server side checkout (1s)
[14:21:43]Step 1/1: Visual Studio (sln) (4s)
[14:21:43][Step 1/1] Starting: C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\792fe8e34d5b0582 "/msbuildPath:C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe"
[14:21:43][Step 1/1] in directory: C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\792fe8e34d5b0582
[14:21:45][Step 1/1] MainSolution.sln.teamcity: Build target: TeamCity_Generated_Build (1s)
[14:21:45][MainSolution.sln.teamcity] TeamCity_Generated_Build (1s)
[14:21:45][TeamCity_Generated_Build] MSBuild (1s)
[14:21:45][MSBuild] MainSolution.sln: Build target: Rebuild (1s)
[14:21:45][MainSolution.sln] ValidateSolutionConfiguration
[14:21:45][MainSolution.sln] Rebuild (1s)
[14:21:45][Rebuild] MSBuild (1s)
[14:21:45][MSBuild] C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\792fe8e34d5b0582\MainSolution.sln.metaproj error MSB3202: The project file "C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\792fe8e34d5b0582\..\LibSolution\LibSolution\LibSolution.csproj" was not found.
[14:21:45][MSBuild] MainSolution\MainSolution.csproj: Build target: Rebuild (1s)
[14:21:45][MainSolution\MainSolution.csproj] CoreClean
[14:21:45][MainSolution\MainSolution.csproj] GetReferenceAssemblyPaths
[14:21:45][MainSolution\MainSolution.csproj] PrepareForBuild
[14:21:45][MainSolution\MainSolution.csproj] ResolveProjectReferences
[14:21:45][MainSolution\MainSolution.csproj] ResolveAssemblyReferences
[14:21:46][MainSolution\MainSolution.csproj] CoreCompile
[14:21:46][CoreCompile] Csc
[14:21:46][Csc] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\mscorlib.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\MainSolution.exe /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:exe /utf8output Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\AmsCI\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
**[14:21:46][Csc] Program.cs(1, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'LibSolution' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
[14:21:47][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[14:21:47][Step 1/1] MSBuild output
[14:21:47][Step 1/1] Step Visual Studio (sln) failed
[14:21:47]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:22:49]Build finished
```

From the looks of it, it can't find the csproj because by default, teamcity puts each solution in their own working folder for building, so the paths broke. I tried having teamcity checkout to the same directory, but since each solution is in its own build config, team city throws an error about two different configurations sharing the same folder. Is there a way for Team City(8.1) build the main project?

Comment: You'll need to get somebody else involved with setting up this build server.  The way you are heading is going to end up very poorly, you are referencing assemblies in the GAC.  That's very, very bad and causes runtime errors that are exceedingly hard to diagnose.  The build error is another mistake, very unclear what might cause it since there is no hint whatsoever that it attempts to build the dependent projects.  Ask for help from a team mate that can look over your shoulder to see what you are doing wrong.  And do consider *not* using teamcity, clearly it isn't helping you.

Comment: Where do you see me referencing assemblies in the GAC? The sample project only has one added reference, that's to an another project in another solution. Also, I think the build error is pretty clear, its saying that the path to the project being referenced is wrong. Which is correct, since originally, the two solution folders are siblings, now they're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to the answer on the jetbrains forum post: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5524301

I was able to get things working like I wanted by going to the build configuration, set the checkout directory to custom path

- for refenced solution C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\parent\
- for main solution C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\parent\

ran the builds and it worked.